# UDP java socket programing, upon receiving of data it becomes weird characters

Tags: java, sockets, encryption, cryptography, udp

I have passed a string thru the RC4 cipher which gives me this "™á›*:¢ÞÒ>¥%"

Thereafter, i sent it over by using this code

```
DatagramPacket C1C2 = new DatagramPacket(RC4cipherData, RC4cipherData.length, IPAddress,9876 );
clientSocket.send(C1C2);
```

So once i received in on the host/server side using this code

```
socket.receive( packet );
test = packet.getData();
System.out.println(new String(test));
```

I get this ��*:���>�, which i tried to decrypt using RC4 but failed, but using the above cipher text i was able to get back my plain text.

Additional data if you guys need

```
 byte[] RC4cipherData = rc4.encryptMessage(RC4ptext, RK.toString());
```

Can anyone explained what caused the cipher text to turn into those weird characters?

RC4 code

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Implementation of RC4 stream cipher
 *
 * @author Iurii Sergiichuk
 */
public class RC4 {
    private static final int SBOX_LENGTH = 256;
    private static final int KEY_MIN_LENGTH = 5;
    /**
     * Key array
     */
    private byte[] key = new byte[SBOX_LENGTH - 1];
    /**
     * Sbox
     */
    private int[] sbox = new int[SBOX_LENGTH];

    public RC4() {
        reset();
    }

    public RC4(String key) throws InvalidKeyException {
        this();
        setKey(key);
    }

    private void reset() {
        Arrays.fill(key, (byte) 0);
        Arrays.fill(sbox, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Encrypt given message String with given Charset and key
     *
     * @param message message to be encrypted
     * @param charset charset of message
     * @param key     key
     * @return encrypted message
     * @throws InvalidKeyException if key length is smaller than 5 or bigger than 255
     */
    public byte[] encryptMessage(String message, Charset charset, String key)
            throws InvalidKeyException {
        reset();
        setKey(key);
        byte[] crypt = crypt(message.getBytes());
        reset();
        return crypt;
    }

    /**
     * Encrypt given message String with given Key and pre-defined UTF-8 charset
     *
     * @param message message to be encrypted
     * @param key     key
     * @return encrypted message
     * @throws InvalidKeyException if key length is smaller than 5 or bigger than 255
     * @see StandardCharsets
     */
    public byte[] encryptMessage(String message, String key)
            throws InvalidKeyException {
        return encryptMessage(message, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, key);
    }

    /**
     * Decrypt given byte[] message array with given charset and key
     *
     * @param message message to be decrypted
     * @param charset charset of message
     * @param key     key
     * @return string in given charset
     * @throws InvalidKeyException if key length is smaller than 5 or bigger than 255
     */
    public String decryptMessage(byte[] message, Charset charset, String key)
            throws InvalidKeyException {
        reset();
        setKey(key);
        byte[] msg = crypt(message);
        reset();
        return new String(msg);
    }

    /**
     * Decrypt given byte[] message array with given key and pre-defined UTF-8
     * charset
     *
     * @param message message to be decrypted
     * @param key     key
     * @return string in given charset
     * @throws InvalidKeyException if key length is smaller than 5 or bigger than 255
     * @see StandardCharsets
     */
    public String decryptMessage(byte[] message, String key)
            throws InvalidKeyException {
        return decryptMessage(message, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, key);
    }

    /**
     * Crypt given byte array. Be aware, that you must init key, before using
     * crypt.
     *
     * @param msg array to be crypt
     * @return crypted byte array
     * @see <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4#Pseudo-random_generation_algorithm_.28PRGA.29">Pseudo-random generation algorithm</a>
     */
    public byte[] crypt(final byte[] msg) {
        sbox = initSBox(key);
        byte[] code = new byte[msg.length];
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for (int n = 0; n < msg.length; n++) {
            i = (i + 1) % SBOX_LENGTH;
            j = (j + sbox[i]) % SBOX_LENGTH;
            swap(i, j, sbox);
            int rand = sbox[(sbox[i] + sbox[j]) % SBOX_LENGTH];
            code[n] = (byte) (rand ^ msg[n]);
        }
        return code;
    }

    /**
     * Initialize SBOX with given key. Key-scheduling algorithm
     *
     * @param key key
     * @return sbox int array
     * @see <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4#Key-scheduling_algorithm_.28KSA.29">Wikipedia. Init sbox</a>
     */
    private int[] initSBox(byte[] key) {
        int[] sbox = new int[SBOX_LENGTH];
        int j = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < SBOX_LENGTH; i++) {
            sbox[i] = i;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < SBOX_LENGTH; i++) {
            j = (j + sbox[i] + (key[i % key.length]) & 0xFF) % SBOX_LENGTH;
            swap(i, j, sbox);
        }
        return sbox;
    }

    private void swap(int i, int j, int[] sbox) {
        int temp = sbox[i];
        sbox[i] = sbox[j];
        sbox[j] = temp;
    }

    /**
     * Setup key
     *
     * @param key key to be setup
     * @throws InvalidKeyException if key length is smaller than 5 or bigger than 255
     */
    public void setKey(String key) throws InvalidKeyException {
        if (!(key.length() >= KEY_MIN_LENGTH && key.length() < SBOX_LENGTH)) {
            throw new InvalidKeyException("Key length has to be between "
                    + KEY_MIN_LENGTH + " and " + (SBOX_LENGTH - 1));
        }

        this.key = key.getBytes();
    }

}

/**
 * Exception made for recognise invalid keys
 *
 * @author Iurii Sergiichuk
 */
class InvalidKeyException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2412232436238451574L;

    public InvalidKeyException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```

Server Code

```
   socket.receive( packet );
             test = packet.getData();
            // test = new byte[packet.getlength()];
             System.out.println(new String(test));
```

Client Code

```
 byte[] RC4cipherData = rc4.encryptMessage(RC4ptext, RK.toString());
                System.out.println("encryption: " + new String(RC4cipherData));
                String RC4decryptData = rc4.decryptMessage(RC4cipherData, RK.toString());
                System.out.println("decryption: " + RC4decryptData);
                //time to send C1 and C2 encrypted to server/alice
                String C1C2PText = encryptedRK.toString() + "%" + new String(RC4cipherData) + "%";
                System.out.println("Test: " + C1C2PText);
                byte [] C1C2data = C1C2PText.getBytes();

                //System.out.println("Print conversion: " + C1C2data[0].);
               // DatagramPacket C1C2 = new DatagramPacket(C1C2data, C1C2data.length, IPAddress,9876 );
                DatagramPacket C1C2 = new DatagramPacket(RC4cipherData, RC4cipherData.length, IPAddress,9876 );
                clientSocket.send(C1C2);
```

Comment: The cipher text is just raw bytes, so `new String(RC4cipherData)` doen't make sense as does `new String(test)`

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone explained what caused the cipher text to turn into those weird characters?

You did. Ciphertext, err, *is* weird characters. Try decrypting it before printing. When you do, make sure only to use `packet.getLength()` bytes from each datagram, unlike what you're doing now.

Comment: after encyption it was this ™á›*:¢ÞÒ>¥%.. but after sending it over it became ��*:���>�, which when i decrypted didnt give me my plaintext. but this ™á›*:¢ÞÒ>¥% gives me my plaintext

Comment: It's irrelevant what it looks like until you decrypt it. Your real problem here is the decryption, and it is undoubtedly due to not using `packet.getLength()`.

Comment: This is a test code i developed. i understand the issue of only using the exact bytes for the data, which i actually did as in my actual code i put a delimiter at the end of my code, so i can split it into different strings, therefore is no extra data. But i will show you the result now

Comment: something like this ? 
data = new byte[packet.getLength()];

Comment: Suppose you post your actual decryption code so we can all see it and comment on it?

Comment: The server code is still doing nothing more than printing the ciphertext, and your `decryptMessage()` methods call `crypt()`, which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: printing the cipher text to check what i have received and i have received gibberish. it calls crypt to decrypt. i suspect this is something to do with utf encoding

Comment: No it isn't. Base-63 is immune to UTF encoding. Your problem is that you aren't decrypting correctly. Pay attenion.